# Simulate lasting key press

Tags: c++, winapi, keystroke

In my Program I want to simulate key presses. For example I want to say Press(KeyA, 1000), where the first parameter is the KeyCode and the second is the time in millisekonds. KeyA and so on are typedefs and the methods are working perfectly for just pressing the button once.

```cpp
void PressKey(INPUT &ip, int keycode, int ms)
{
    // Press the  key
    ip.ki.wVk = keycode; // virtual-key code for the key
    ip.ki.dwFlags = 0; // 0 for key press
    SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

    sleep(ms);

    // Release the  key
    ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP; // KEYEVENTF_KEYUP for key release
    SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
}

int main()
{


    // input event
    INPUT ip;
    INPUT ipMouse;

    ip.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    ip.ki.wScan = 0; // hardware scan code for key
    ip.ki.time = 0;
    ip.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;



    PressKey(ip, KeyM, 1000);
```

I thought pressing the key, then waiting until releasing it would count as a held button press but it does not. Also I do not want to just say PressKey(ip, KeyM) a thousand times to get the same input as holding the button for 5 seconds. Does anybody now how to make the programm simulate longer inputs?

Comment: What is the target of the keypress? Is it your own program or some other app? How is it not working? The fact that you sleep() would prevent your own mainloop from running during that time. If it is another app, it might either check keyboard scan codes or read inputs.

Comment: I've written an own console game, that I want to compile with different /O Options and then analyze the optimizations in excel. I've got everything set up now, outputting fps and cpu etc in a csv file works perfectly. To really compare the optimizations though, I need always the same input. Thats why I need to hold for example the 'w' key for a fixed time, because my game's movement speed is dependent of the time differencial between the frames. Does that make sense or am I just thinking in the wrong direction. I want the input to be an external programm, so did not hardcode the movement

Comment: Don't record input. Record your game engine's state transitions instead, and replay those.

Comment: Recording inputs is totally fine (did it for multiple AAA games). Replaying it from the mainloop is a good approach. Using the win32 input injection, though, is not the right approach.

Comment: X-Y problem: the right questions are: how do I save inputs and replay them? How do I profile my game? And how do I keep my game logic deterministic?

Comment: @JeffreysupportsMonica what approach is right then? The input injection seemed the best to go with.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer the more general question "How do I replay a run of my game with specific inputs?"

The trick to replay inputs, for profiling, to check determinism or for general QA is to separate two elements from the game processing:

- Any access to the timer
- Any reading of inputs from the player

If your game is well written (no undefined behaviour), with a given set of inputs and associated timings, it should always behave the same. Same inputs at the same time results in the same output.

So, wrap TimeGetTime(), std::clock, rdtsc or whatever you are using to read time into your own getTime() function. Similarly, wrap the win32 input reading and/or scancode reading into your own getInputs().

Run the game, but save all the inputs and timestamps to a file, in addition to using them. **Log.txt** or something. Ideally, your game should ask for the time just once per frame, but hey, I've seen games that queried the current times thousands of time each frame.

Now, modify your game so that instead of getting the real inputs or the real wall clock, it gets the values from the log file. If your game is deterministic, you should now be able to have the same sequence of events replayed.

You can then profile it. Notice that since the time is read from the file, if the game happens to be slower while replayed, it is not an issue. Your characters will jump the same length, fall at the same place, etc... It will just look slower. That allows you to use the most intensive profiling settings, even if the games plays 10 times slower, it still does the exact same and you get valid measurement of where the time was spent.

It also prepares you for a setup where QA can save replays and you can debug.

It is more work to log all this and it requires some care to not have any non-determinism.

But, on the flip-side, if you go with your original suggestion, the input injection will not happen exactly at the same time. You lose some QA repro abilities. From run to run, the behaviour will diverge a bit.

The profiler overhead will also affect timing, making the measurements invalid at times.

So, my suggestion:

- make a close-to-deterministic game (there will most likely always be slight diffs)
- wrap all inputs (including time) behind a logging function
- save them all to record
- replace them with logged history to replay

To address specifically the frame of the question:
Instead of feeding the inputs through the win32 system, the game calls your own getInput() and, when replaying, gets the stored inputs thus bypassing the whole win32 system.

Answer (score 0):

However there is no such API for simulating a key held-press.

When you test a window application, it will receive continuous `WM_KEYDOWN` message when you press and hold a key on keyboard.

If your application is a window application instead of a console application, you can detect the first `WM_KEYDOWN` in a [low level keyboard hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-hooks) and start a timer of 5 seconds, when the timer timeout, send an `WM_KEYUP` message, so that simulate a held-press. You can only call `SendInput` one time and send one key press message.

For console application it can't be hooked, call SendInput repeatedly for a specified time is a solution for you. Any concern about this?